# Core data - Save with an array causing 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship'

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

In core data, I have a relationship which is joined via a bridge entity

The relationship in question is Card ->> Segment ->> Fighter

- A `card` has many `segments`
- A `segment` has many `fighters` A single
- A `fighter` can appear on one `segment`

One segment (or SegmentRow) has an array of fighters attached to it.

A diagram of it can be seen below;

[image: Entity diagram]

The way the app works currently is, a user picks a fighter to add to a segment row.  Once they hit save, the segment rows and fighters assigned to that row are saved.

But I keep getting a relationship error;

> Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'fighters' between objects
>   in different contexts (source = Segment -- Name: Row 0 with 0 fighters
>   , destination = Some fighter)'

Some notes:

The card object doesn't exist yet, this is because the segments need to be saved first; then the card object can be saved.

So my code to save is like this;

```
+ (void) saveSegments:(NSArray *)segments inContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context  withCompletion:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSError *error))completion
{
    int i = 0;
    for (FCSegmentRow *row in segments) {

        FCSegment *segment = [FCSegment MR_createEntityInContext:context];
        segment.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %lu", (unsigned long)i];


        // Fighters
        NSMutableSet *fighters = [NSMutableSet set];

        for (FCFighter *fighter in row.fighters) {
            if (fighter) {
                [fighters addObject:fighter];
            }
        }

        segment.fighters = [NSSet setWithSet:fighters];


        i++;
    }
    [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];


    // Output
    NSArray *allSegments = [self segmentsInContext:context error:nil];
    for (FCSegment *segment in allSegments) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [segment description]);
    }
}
```

The FCSegmentRow is just a simple NSObject with an NSArray *fighters;

In my code, I try to set a mutable set and add fighters to this set, then save it to core data.

Further, I tried to put the saving in a block and wait for completion; but this issue continues to happen.

It appears to be because the fighter is in a different context to the segment I am creating.

So, the question I have is -- how do I store the segment with its fighters (relationship)

Edit:  *Where and how are fighters created?*

With reference to questions

1. The fighters are on their own page (view controller) and has its own managed object context.
2. The page which manages the segments allows a user to pick from a list of fighters; this launches the fighters page and waits for a completion block to "return" the selected fighter.
3. The fighters data comes from Firebase, and loads it into Core data.

The fighters view controller is configured thusly;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.title = @"Pick Fighter";

    self.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_context];

    [self reloadData];
}

// ... 

-(void) reloadData
{
        self.fighterList = [FCFighter findFightersInContext:self.context];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

As seen above, the fighters view controller has its own context

Edit:
Further notes:

A card consists of many segments, I call this a segment row.

On the "segment row view controller" there is 2 buttons per table cell (A segment has 2 fighters), the user can press either button and it fires the fighters page, letting the user select the required fighter.

I tried to pass the same context as is in the segment row view controller into the fighters page, but what happens is that it loses the data from the first button as soon as I press the second button.

IE: 
Press Button A - Pick a fighter .. Joe Bloggs
Press Button B - Pick a fighter .. Mike Smith
When I return to the segment row; Press Button A's fighter is disappeared; and when I check the data its (null).

The code to fire up the fighters page is below;

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard mainStoryboard];
    FCFightersTableViewController *vc = (FCFightersTableViewController *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FCFightersTableViewController"];
    vc.tableCellSelectable = YES;
    vc.excludeFighters = [selectedFightersMutable copy];
    //vc.context = self.context;
    vc.completionBlock = ^(FCFightersTableViewController *vc, FCFighter *fighter) {

        NSLog(@"Picked fighter - %@ (uuid: %@)", fighter.name, fighter.uuid);

        [fightersInRow setObject:fighter atIndexedSubscript:fighterIdx];
        segmentRow.fighters = [fightersInRow copy];


        NSLog(@"selected fighter - %@ (uuid: %@)", fighter.name, fighter.uuid);

        [fightersInRow setObject:fighter atIndexedSubscript:fighterIdx];
        segmentRow.fighters = [fightersInRow copy];

        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    };
```

Comment: Where and how do you create the fighter objects?

Comment: You're right, so you need to tell us more about your contexts and where the fighters come from...

Comment: Hi there.  The fighters are on another page (view controller).  This view contoller has its own managed object context.    So there are 3 pages.  The first is the card.  The second is the management of the segments and the third is the fighters.

Comment: Because Page A launches Page B; does it need to pass over Page A's managed object context?

Comment: @cardigan The Segments and Fighters MUST be in the same context to establish a relationship between them.  Unless you need two contexts for other reasons, then yes, just pass over the context from one VC to the next.  If you do need separate contexts, pass the NSManagedObjectIDs and refetch any objects you need in the second context.

Comment: @pbasdf I tried:  Page A sends Page B a managed object context.  On Page A, each table row has 2 buttons; one per fighter.   If I press button `a`, pick a fighter then return to press button `b`; it loses the first fighter or vice versa.

Comment: What do you mean by refresh any objects?

Comment: @cardigan I think that might be a problem in your completionBlock (I'm suspicious of `setObject:atIndexedSubscript`, which is an insert rather than a replace).  Regarding *refetching* objects using their NSManagedObjectID, if you pass the IDs from one context to another, you can use the context's `objectWithID` method to get the object.

Comment: okay, I'll try this idea

Comment: Hello there. I changed `setObject` to `replaceObject` and I also used your idea of passing the context's objectID from Page B back to Page A, then using ObjectWithID to get the object; this added the fighter correctly and  saves it, many thanks.   I get error: The error is `CoreData: warning: An NSManagedObjectContext delegate overrode fault handling behavior to silently delete the object with ID '0xd000000162900000 <x-coredata://83D3F1FE-3152-44B2-8116-365089F60C51/Fighter/p22692>' and substitute nil/0 for all property values instead of throwing.`   I will just raise another question for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am accepting @pbasdf's answer.

Here's what I did. I didn't use a global context, rather I kept it so that each view controller has its own NSManagedObjectContext.

When a user is on the SegmentRow (Page A) a user can press a button which launches a list of fighters (Page B); a completion block is returned;

```
// (Page A) fires Page B

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard mainStoryboard];
        FCFightersTableViewController *vc = (FCFightersTableViewController *) [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"FCFightersTableViewController"];

        vc.completionBlock = ^(FCFightersTableViewController *vc, NSManagedObjectID *fighterObjectID) {

            FCFighter *fighter = [self.context objectWithID:fighterObjectID];
            NSLog(@"Picked fighter - %@ (uuid: %@)", fighter.name, fighter.uuid);

            [fightersInRow replaceObjectAtIndex:fighterIdx withObject:fighter];
            segmentRow.fighters = [fightersInRow copy];

            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self.tableView endUpdates];
        };
```

Notice I changed it from `setObject` to `replaceObject` as per the above comments.

I also get the `ManagedObjectID` and use the context to get the fighter, as per pbasdf's answer.

```
// (Page B) fighters page fires the completionBlock
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    FCFighter *fighter = nil;
        fighter = [self.fighterList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    if (self.completionBlock)
    {
        self.completionBlock(self, fighter.objectID);
    }

    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }];
}
```

When I come to save it, I now;

```
// Save the segments to Core data
    for (FCSegmentRow *row in segments) {

        FCSegment *segment = [FCSegment MR_createEntityInContext:context];
        segment.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Row %lu", (unsigned long)i];

        [segment addFighters:[NSSet setWithArray:row.fighters]];
    }
    [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];


    // Output log
    NSArray *allSegments = [self segmentsInContext:context error:nil];
    for (FCSegment *segment in allSegments) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [segment description]);
        for (FCFighter *fighter in [segment.fighters allObjects]) {
            NSLog(@"Fighter -- %@", fighter.name);
        }
    }
```

Although I get a core data error I will put this in another question, when I hit the output log it displays the fighters for the given segment.

I have to do some checks to see if its persisting and fetching the objects correctly; but other than this I am accepting @pbasdf's answer.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just wondering why you are using several contexts?  Its way more complicated to manage and Ive only found it necessary when using multi-threading - for example when instantiating a very large amount of objects that might render the main thread slow for the UI.  Coredata can mostly do its stuff with one context just fine and you won't notice any slowness.  Managing multiple contexts requires lots of planning and might be totally unnecessary in your case (but apologies if you have no choice).

The other thing though - you shouldnt need to go creating NSSets of things then adding them to other objects.  Coredata has all that stuff covered (particularly if you automatically create the objects from coredata).  NSSets will be ready to go and you should only have to create objects in your main context and set their relationship properties - parents, etc.

Comment: I thought I was meant to have several contexts, they all refer the main default context.  If I don't need to create NSSet (mutable or otherwise) for the relationships, is it just a case of "addFighter"  -- I tried this, but it gives the same error of `illegal attempt of relationships`

Comment: Are you stating that there should be one context, perhaps defined in the application delegate and use this one? I will try that

Comment: Using multiple contexts is an established best practice. Contexts are lightweight and should represent a scratchpad of changes.

Comment: So each view controller is okay to have its own context?

Comment: @cardigan its massively overkill, in my opinion.  Theres just no need.  Easy way, also fine by apple, is to have the managed object context as a property on the app delegate.  Then just import the app delegate wherever you need to in your app and use that context.  Much easier, totally fine by apple best practises, and will save you a ton of headaches.  Having multiple contexts is also fine, by you need to have a good reason, such as threading.  One for each view controller is really not required.

Comment: @cardigan its a pleasure :)